# The second field in /etc/shadow shows "!*" for user "bin" , "uucp" and few other service accounts as well. Can anyome explain the reason for !*?

Tags: etc, shadow

The second field in /etc/shadow shows "!*" for user "bin" , "uucp" and few other service accounts as well. Can anyone explain the reason for "!*" ?

Comment: Hi Anthony, Need to know in what cases we get "*!" in the field. Information provided for * or ! but I need !and * ..

Answer (score 1):

as per man page

```
 man 5 shadow
```

> If the password field contains some string that is not a valid result of crypt(3), for instance ! or *, the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

Comment: can we manually set "!*" for any user ?

Comment: nobody:!*:16259:0:99999:7:::
avahi:!!:16259:0:99999:7:::
Why !* and !! for above account ?